# Using promise in connection string password field returns database not connected

Tags: node.js, graphql, pg-promise, koa2, aws-sdk-nodejs

Decrypting password from environment parameter using aws.kms gets not resolved to use in pg-promise connection object. Database can not connect because of empty password. Password gets resolved after about one second from my local machine, long after the koa server is ready. I tried everything to get GraphQL wait for the database connection, but i couldn't find much information to my problem.

When using environment password direct everything works as intended.

## My db.init.js

```
const pgp = require("pg-promise")();
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const kms = new aws.KMS({
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEYID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY,
    region: process.env.REGION
});
let params = {
    CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(
        process.env.ENCRYPTED_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        "base64"
    )
};
module.exports = kms.decrypt(params, async (err, data) => {
    const password = await data.Plaintext.toString("utf-8");
    const cn = {
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
        user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
        password: password,
    };
    return pgp(cn);
});
```

## Works when changing db.init.js to

(using plain password instead of encrypted password):

```
const pgp = require("pg-promise")();
const cn = {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.PLAIN_DATABASE_PASSWORD
};
module.exports = pgp(cn);
```

## Using it in schema:

```
const { GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString} = require("graphql");
const db = require("./db.init")
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: "RootQueryType",
        fields: () => ({
            sql: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                async resolve() {
                    return await db
                        .any("SELECT * FROM user;")
                        .then(data => data[0].name)
                        .catch(err => `Something went wrong: ${err}`);
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
module.exports = schema;
```

## Server file

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const mount = require('koa-mount');
const graphqlHTTP = require('koa-graphql');
const schema = require('./schemas');
function createServer() {
    server.use(
        mount(
            '/graphql',
            graphqlHTTP({
                schema,
                graphiql: true,
            })
        )
    );
    return server;
}
```

## Local Server

```
const server = require("./server");
const port = 4000;
server().listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}/graphql`);
});
```

## Lambda function

```
const awsServerlessKoa = require('aws-serverless-koa');
const serverlessMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-koa/middleware');
const server = require('./server');
server().use(serverlessMiddleware());
module.exports.handler = awsServerlessKoa(server);
```

GraphQL gives failure: "db.any is not a function". In the db object in schema.js is still the unresolved aws kms object in the connection. I didn't try this as a lambda function because i have to make sure that the database is ready when the function fires.

Comment: How do you expect it to work, if in the first example you are not exporting the `db` object, rather a function that returns it. And then you are importing it as if it exports the database object directly. The error about `any` method not existing on the returned function seems like the obvious result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment vitaly-t, I figured it finally out:

#### db.init.js

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const kms = new aws.KMS({
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEYID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY,
  region: process.env.REGION,
});
const params = {
  CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    'base64',
  ),
};
async function getDb() {
  return kms
    .decrypt(params)
    .promise()
    .then(async res => {
      const password = await res.Plaintext.toString('utf-8');
      return pgp({
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
        user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
        password,
      });
    });
}
module.exports = getDb();
```

#### schema.js

```
const { importSchema } = require('graphql-import');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');
const dbp = require('../db/init');
const schema = importSchema('src/api/schemas.graphql');
module.exports = dbp.then(db => {
  const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      user: () => {
        return db
          .any('SELECT * FROM user;')
          .then(data => data[0].name);
      },
    },
  };
  return makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
  });
});
```

#### schemas.graphql

`type Query {
      user: String
    }
    schema {
      query: Query
    }`

#### server.js

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const mount = require('koa-mount');
const graphqlHTTP = require('koa-graphql');
const schema = require('../api/schemas');
function createServer() {
  const server = new Koa();
  server.use(
    mount(
      '/graphql',
      graphqlHTTP(async () => ({
        schema: await schema,
        graphiql: true,
      })),
    ),
  );
  return server;
}
module.exports = createServer;
```

#### server.local.js

```
const server = require('./server');
const port = 4000;
server().listen(port, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}/graphql`);
});
```

Only the lambda function I didn't test. Should be straight forward.